# Docker + Rspec + Cuprite / receiving a blank page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, rspec, cuprite

I have a (Rails 5.2, Ruby 2.5.8) working app configured with docker and I'm having problems running my system tests with Rspec and Cuprite.

I've followed [this guide](https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/system-of-a-test-setting-up-end-to-end-rails-testing) to set everything up, but when I run the test suite, all system specs fail.

I tried running simple tests, like visiting a page and checking a text existence, but they are always red.
I check the screenshots generated by running the tests, and the only thing I see is a blank page. I see the same thing when I debug it with cuprite, using `page.driver.pause`.

I added a binding.pry in the controller action and it doesn't seem to get to that point.

This is the error I see:

```
Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_text('Foo')
       expected to find text "Foo" in ""
```

This is my configuration:

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
  rspec_system:
    build: .
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    depends_on:
      - db
      - chrome
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app:cached
      - bundler:/usr/local/bundle:delegated
      - bootsnap_cache:/usr/src/bootsnap:delegated
      - rails_cache:/usr/src/app/tmp/cache:delegated
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@db:5432/
      - CHROME_URL=http://chrome:3333
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'

  chrome:
    image: barrenechea/browserless:latest
    ports:
      - "3333:3333"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app:cached
    environment:
      PORT: 3333
      CONNECTION_TIMEOUT: 600000
```

spec/support/cuprite_setup.rb

```rb
REMOTE_CHROME_URL = ENV["CHROME_URL"]
REMOTE_CHROME_HOST, REMOTE_CHROME_PORT =
  if REMOTE_CHROME_URL
    URI.parse(REMOTE_CHROME_URL).yield_self do |uri|
      [uri.host, uri.port]
    end
  end

# Check whether the remote chrome is running and configure the Capybara
# driver for it.
remote_chrome =
  begin
    if REMOTE_CHROME_URL.nil?
      false
    else
      Socket.tcp(REMOTE_CHROME_HOST, REMOTE_CHROME_PORT, connect_timeout: 1).close
      true
    end
  rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED, Errno::EHOSTUNREACH, SocketError
    false
  end

remote_options = remote_chrome ? {url: REMOTE_CHROME_URL} : {}

require "capybara/cuprite"

Capybara.register_driver(:better_cuprite) do |app|
  Capybara::Cuprite::Driver.new(
    app,
    **{
      window_size: [2560, 1440],
      browser_options: remote_chrome ? {"no-sandbox" => nil} : {},
      inspector: true
    }.merge(remote_options)
  )
end

Capybara.default_driver = Capybara.javascript_driver = :better_cuprite
```

```rb
  config.prepend_before(:each, type: :system) do
    driven_by Capybara.javascript_driver
  end
```

```rb
Capybara.server_host = "0.0.0.0"
Capybara.app_host = "http://#{ENV.fetch("APP_HOST", `hostname`.strip&.downcase || "0.0.0.0")}"
```